# How does Promise run when .then method is not called?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I create two promises, but I do not run the then method on those promises. Yet once the promise objects go out of scope, the promise code runs as if `.then` was called.

How is a `Promise` settled without a call to the `.then` method?

I am asking because I would like to load an array with `Promise` objects and then run the promises in sequence.

```js
function promises_createThenRun() {
  const p1 = createPromise1();
  const p2 = createPromise2();

  console.log('before hello');
  alert('hello');
  console.log('after hello');
  // the two promises run at this point.  What makes them run?
}

function createPromise1() {
  let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timer 1');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
  return p1;
}

function createPromise2() {
  let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timer 2');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  return p2;
}
```

Comment: Why would you think that the `setTimeout()` callbacks would not be called?

Comment: Just because you aren't using .then doesn't mean the function won't continue to execute.

Comment: asking when are the setTimeout callbacks called.  They appear to be called when the promise goes out of scope.

Answer (score 27):

The code inside the Promise constructor runs when the promise is created and it runs synchronously which surprises some people. So even without `then()` everything still runs.

```js
new Promise(resolve => console.log("running"))
```

Code in the callback for the `setTimeout` however, doesn't run until it's called, but it too will run even without the `then()`

```js
new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log("promise created")
  setTimeout(() => console.log("this runs later"), 1000)
})
```

Comment: but in my code I create the promise.  Then run alert( ) to pause the code. The promise code does not run until after the alert.   The promise code does not run until the promise objects are destroyed?   Like there is a deconstructor?

Comment: @StephenRichter - yeah, I can see how that makes things confusing. `alert()` pauses timers so even though the promise runs (which you can confirm by putting a `console.log()` outside the `setTimeout`) the timers won't fire until you close the dialog box.

Comment: p.s. @StephenRichter here's a good thread on the timer issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487403/why-do-js-modal-message-boxes-pause-countdown-on-settimeout

Comment: @10101010 I think it answers the question that was asked. If you disagree, you should contribute an answer.

Answer (score 16):

When calling `.then` you just set up a "callback" which says what should happen after the promise is done. So the promise will be called, with or without declaring such callback.

Imagine the promise that calls a AJAX request. Calling `.then` and passing a function to it will make it run when the ajax call was finished (successfully or not as in timeout or other errors). But not calling `.then` will not stop the request to be run. You will simply not react to the results of the request.

Answer (score 3):

I thought, that "Promises won't run" if you don't call then/catch/finally on them, too. But if you consider, that these methods return new Promises, and according to your logic, you need to call then/catch/finally on these returned Promises in order to "run" them, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop)))